Can I download a static asset with a given url in PHP
I'm debugging a 3rd party open source application, and there is a method that compress pdf files in a zip file and then stores it in the static folder. Then an email is sent with an url that is made of the zip file path in the static folder. However when I follow the link, it doesn't point to the file, but rather to an error indicating that the controller doesn't exists.
This is the code that compress the file and stores it inside the static folder:
$compress = 'zip';
Utility_File::compress(
                $dir, ['format'=>$compress, 'delete'=>true, 'download'=>false]
            );
$output = $dir.'.'.$compress;
$filename = DIR_STATIC.'/pdfs/'.basename($output);
if (!rename($output, $filename)) {
    $pdf = 'Error al mover el archivo comprimido al directorio de descarga';
} else {
    $pdf = core\Configure::read('app.url_static').'/zip_files/'.basename($filename).' (link is valid for 24 hours)';
}

When I access the link provided it displays the following error:
Controller_Pdfs not found

I'm very new to php, so I'd like if what am currently trying is even possible or do I need to implement more complex things. Any help would be much appreciated.

I think this question is a bit misleading, to say the least. What you're asking here is how some undisclosed framework handles routing. That's impossible to know without seeing the source code. I'm assuming the application is not entirely broken, so perhaps you've missed some of the web server setup instructions.

I think easy way to download and save file from an website by php would be like
<?php
function downloadFile($fileUrl, $pathForSave)
{

    $fileContent = file_get_contents($fileUrl);

    if($fileContent === FALSE)
    {
        die('Error: Unable to download the file.');
    }

    $fileSaved = file_put_contents($pathForSave, $fileContent);

    if($fileSaved === FALSE)
    {
        die('Error: Unable to save the file.');
    }
}

downloadFile('https://www.php.net/images/logos/php-logo.svg', __DIR__);

